# How to use one index function for two different controllers?

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I am trying to code a social media website like facebook, in Laravel 5.8.
I have in `/home` and in `/profile` the same list of your friends, but two different controllers (HomeController & ProfileController). I do not want to copy paste the same code for two different controllers. How can I solve it, so I only have to use my code once?

**HomeController.php**

```
public function index()
    {
        $friends = [];
        $friendsID = Person_has_person::select('person2')->where('person1', Auth::user()->id)->get();
        foreach ($friendsID as $friendID)
            $friends[] = User::find($friendID->person2);

        return view('home')->with('friends', $friends);
    }
```

**ProfileController.php**

```
public function index()
    {
        $friends = [];
        $friendsID = Person_has_person::select('person2')->where('person1', Auth::user()->id)->get();
        foreach ($friendsID as $friendID)
            $friends[] = User::find($friendID->person2);

        return view('profile')->with('friends', $friends);
    }
```

In my web.php file I have my routes.

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/profile', 'ProfileController@index');
```

In my template I use this to show my friends.

```
@if(count($friends) > 0)
    @foreach($friends as $friend)
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/profile/{{$friend->id}}">{{$friend->firstname . ' ' . $friend->lastname}}</a>
                <a class="text-danger"
                   href="/removeFriend/{{Auth::user()->id . '/' . $friend->id}}">[unfriend]</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    @endforeach
@else
    <p>No friends available</p>
@endif
```

As you can see I have the same code in two different Controllers. That's not a good solution. Can you give me an advice how can I code it so I only have it once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why my answer was deleted by an administrator here.. But here it is again. [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#view-composers) is perfect for this situation. And you can register the composer within the `boot` method either of the `AppServiceProvider` or you can create your own service provider and register it in the `config/app.php` `providers` array.

```
View::composer(
    ['home', 'profile'],
    'App\Http\View\Composers\YourViewComposer'
);
```

and the compose method shares the same code:

```
/**
* Bind data to the view.
*
* @param  View  $view
* @return void
*/
public function compose(View $view)
{
    $friends = [];
    $friendsID = Person_has_person::select('person2')->where('person1', Auth::user()->id)->get();

    foreach ($friendsID as $friendID)
    {
       $friends[] = User::find($friendID->person2);
    }

    $view->with('friends', $friends);
}
```

Comment: I am trying your solution and I'm struggling a little bit. Seems like the compose function is not enough, I would also need a FriendListComposer Class. In this class I have to use a repository. Why do I have to create a repository?
I saw this in the laravel docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#view-composers

Comment: Yes, you need to create a composer class, I just gave you what needs to be in your compose function. Repository is a design pattern, you can but you don't have to use it. What I've shown you above is enough.

Comment: And don't forget to replace this `'App\Http\View\Composers\YourViewComposer'` with the path to your composer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to invoke `index` method from other `controller`:

```
use ProfileController;

class HomeController {
    public function index()
    {
         ProfileController::index();
    }
}
```

Comment: Already tried that. It does work, but calling a method from one controller to another should not be used.
See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53209299/laravel-how-to-call-a-function-from-another-controller

Comment: Hmm.. May be you should write some helper class, which will do same job, what your `index` method does here. And then use this helper class' `index` method in these two `conroller`s

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you make two different `Routes` pointing to the same Controller action?

Like,

`Route::get('/home', 'ProfileController@index');
Route::get('/profile', 'ProfileController@index');`

What is the issue with that?

Comment: Because there are other functions in each controller which are not the same.

Comment: Have you seen what I am suggesting? I am just asking you to make two different routes pointing the same index function.